How to execute a function passed as a string argument?
An application has some buttons on a screen that should execute different functions when clicked. It goes like a little like this:
<template>
<ul>
<li v-for="MenuItem in MenuItems">
  <button type="button" @click.prevent="handleClick({Function: MenuItem.Function.Name, Params: MenuItem.Function.Params })">
              {{ MenuItem.Label }}
  </button>
</li>
</ul>
</template>

<script setup>
const MenuItems = [
{
              Label: `Edit`,
              Function: {
                Name: `editItem`,
                Params: {
                  ItemID: 1
                }
 },
{
              Label: `Delete`,
              Function: {
                Name: `deleteItem`,
                Params: {
                  ItemID: 1
                }
 }
]

function handleClick({Function, Params}) {
   Function.apply(Params) // throws not a function error
   eval(Function+"()")    // throws not a fuction error
}

function editItem(){
console.log(`edit item`);
}

function deleteItem(){
console.log(`about to delete item`);
}
</script>

All I want to do is run whatever has been passed to the Function argument in handleClick() and also include the Params argument as an argument to the Function that needs to be executed e.g. editItem(1) or deleteItem(1);
Trying apply() and eval() don't seem to work and throws an error that Uncaught TypeError: Function.apply is not a function. I am using VueJS as the framework, but this is really a Javascript question.

It's misleading to call a function "Function" because it shadows a global with the same name, this can cause false positives in linters because the use of Function is a form of eval

@EstusFlask okay, I have renamed it to ExecFunction because I didnt know there was a conflict

Make the functions as methods of an object and call the methods:
Playground
const Functions = {
  editItem,
  deleteItem
};

function handleClick({Function, Params}) {
  Functions[Function](Params);
}



I didn't know about this and can see that your solution works, but on the Vue site it says Usage of getCurrentInstance is strongly discouraged in application code - so is this safe to use?

@volumeone fixed, please check

This is great, and it means MenuItems can be passed in a as a prop as well from other components

Is there any documentation on this? I would never have known how to go about it without this answer.

@volumeone in JS you could try to call a function with eval() but it's not recommended, so you need some reference to a function, here we just collect the functions in an object and call them as methods of the object. It's related to JS rather, not Vue here

You can check this out. It should help you.
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="MenuItem in MenuItems">
      <button
        type="button"
        @click.prevent="
          handleClick({ Function: MenuItem.Function.Name, Params: MenuItem.Function.Params })
        "
      >
        {{ MenuItem.Label }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
const MenuItems = [
  {
    Label: `Edit`,
    Function: {
      Name: `editItem`,
      Params: {
        ItemID: 1,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    Label: `Delete`,
    Function: {
      Name: `deleteItem`,
      Params: {
        ItemID: 1,
      },
    },
  },
]

function handleClick({ Function, Params }) {
  this[Function](Params) // this define the scope for the functions
}

const editItem = function (Params) {
  console.log('edit item with - ' + JSON.stringify(Params))
}

const deleteItem = function (Params) {
  console.log('about to delete item - ' + JSON.stringify(Params))
}
</script>


The Function property in your MenuItems array is not a reference to an actual function. It's a string (editItem, deleteItem), and you cannot call or apply a string like a function.
To fix the problem, you can pass actual function references instead of strings in the MenuItems array. Here's the corrected code:
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="MenuItem in MenuItems" :key="MenuItem.Label">
      <button 
        type="button" 
        @click.prevent="handleClick(MenuItem.Function, MenuItem.Function.Params)">
        {{ MenuItem.Label }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
function editItem(ItemID) {
  console.log(`edit item with ID: ${ItemID}`);
}

function deleteItem(ItemID) {
  console.log(`about to delete item with ID: ${ItemID}`);
}

// Pass actual function references in the MenuItems array
const MenuItems = [
  {
    Label: 'Edit',
    Function: {
      Name: editItem,
      Params: { ItemID: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    Label: 'Delete',
    Function: {
      Name: deleteItem,
      Params: { ItemID: 1 }
    }
  }
];

// Use `Function` directly as a function reference
function handleClick(Function, Params) {
  Function(Params.ItemID);
}
</script>


MenuItem.Function is an object, can't be called

I reviewed your code.
Please try with this codebase.
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="MenuItem in MenuItems" :key="MenuItem.Label">
      <button type="button" @click.prevent="handleClick(MenuItem.Function)">
        {{ MenuItem.Label }}
      </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script setup>
function editItem(params) {
  console.log(`Editing item with ID: ${params.ItemID}`);
}

function deleteItem(params) {
  console.log(`Deleting item with ID: ${params.ItemID}`);
}

const MenuItems = [
  {
    Label: `Edit`,
    Function: {
      Name: editItem, // Pass the actual function reference
      Params: {
        ItemID: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    Label: `Delete`,
    Function: {
      Name: deleteItem, // Pass the actual function reference
      Params: {
        ItemID: 1
      }
    }
  }
];

function handleClick(FunctionObject) {
  const { Name, Params } = FunctionObject;
  Name(Params); // Invoke the function with parameters
}
</script>

Thanks

the functions will be removed in the production

@AlexanderNenashev It's ok as it accesses them from "Function" object, as in another answer

I have upvoted but the answer from @AlexanderNenashev lets me pass MenuItems as a prop which is more useful. MenuItems could come from anywhere - even a store in the future.

How does this solve issue? Please explain the changes you've made. Code-only answers are not good answers.
